# How to escape slashes in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

According to the [json](http://www.json.org) specs, escaping "`/`" is optional.

Gson does not do it by default, but I am dealing with a webservice which is expecting escaped "`/`". So what I want to send is "`somestring\\/someotherstring`". Any ideas on how to achieve this?

To make things clearer: if I try to deserialize "`\\/`" with Gson, it will send "`\\\\/`", which is **not** what I want!

Comment: `String someString = "/";
 someString = someString.replace("/", "\\/");
 System.out.println(someString);`

outputs:
>> \/

Comment: @Selim that does not help. Check my edit

Comment: @stoefln Selim meant: do the replace AFTER the serialization (i.e. on the JSON string), not before.

Comment: Probably a custom TypeAdapter might help: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html

Comment: @stoefln Added an answer which may cover your needs :) let me know if you need additional support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Answer: The Custom Serializer**

You can write your own Custom Serializer - I have created one which follows the rule that you want `/` to be `\\/` but if the string is already escaped you want it to stay `\\/` and not be `\\\\/`.

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29396608;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class EscapeStringSerializer implements JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(String src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        src = createEscapedString(src);
        return new JsonPrimitive(src);
    }

    private String createEscapedString(String src) {
        // StringBuilder for the new String
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        // First occurrence
        int index = src.indexOf('/');
        // lastAdded starting at position 0
        int lastAdded = 0;

        while (index >= 0) {
            // append first part without a /
            builder.append(src.substring(lastAdded, index));

            // if / doesn't have a \ directly in front - add a \
            if (index - 1 >= 0 && !src.substring(index - 1, index).equals("\\")) {
                builder.append("\\");
                // if we are at index 0 we also add it because - well it's the
                // first character
            } else if (index == 0) {
                builder.append("\\");
            }

            // change last added to index
            lastAdded = index;
            // change index to the new occurrence of the /
            index = src.indexOf('/', index + 1);
        }

        // add the rest of the string
        builder.append(src.substring(lastAdded, src.length()));
        // return the new String
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This will create from the following String:

```
"12 /first /second \\/third\\/fourth\\//fifth"`
```

the output:

```
"12 \\/first \\/second \\/third\\/fourth\\/\\/fifth"
```

**Register your Custom Serializer**

Than of course you need to pass this serializer to Gson on Setup like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new EscapeStringSerializer()).create();
String json = gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

---

## **Downloadable & executable Example**

You can find this answer and the exact example in my github stackoverflow answers repo:

[Gson CustomSerializer to escape a String in a special way by DominikAngerer](https://github.com/DominikAngerer/StackoverflowJavaAnswers/tree/master/src/main/java/com/dominikangerer/q29396608)

---

## **See also**

- [Gson User Guide - Custom serializers and deserializers](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ)