# Kotlin escaping forward slashes usign Gson

Tags: kotlin, gson, escaping

I've got this string that I want to send to a backend. In this string, there are several forward slashes, that is basically code that is commented out. It could look like:

```
val string = "// SOME STUFF

// OTHER TEXT ***************************************************
// THIS WOULD CONTINUE FORWARD"
```

So to escape this entire String, I'm using Gson().toJson(string). This would give a result like

```
"// SOME STUFF\r\n\r\n// OTHER TEXT ***************************************************\r\n// THIS WOULD CONTINUE FORWARD"
```

But if I put this into a website that can escape strings for me, I would get

```
"\/\/ SOME STUFF\r\n\r\n\/\/ OTHER TEXT ***************************************************\r\n\/\/ THIS WOULD CONTINUE FORWARD"
```

This bottom part, is what the backend would accept, and the top part it rejects. Is there any way I can do this in a different way, to make Gson look like the bottom part? This is sent as JSON btw, so as

```
{
 "stuff": "THE ESCAPED STRING"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape slashes in Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396608/how-to-escape-slashes-in-gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of failed, and the Gson library didn't help at all. Ended up using Apache's StringEscapeUtils to fix the issue for me, with the StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson method.