# How to convert String to JSON Object in Kotlin Android

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, object

I need help to convert String in JSON object.

This is the response I am getting from WebView

```
 webView.evaluateJavascript(
                    "document.getElementById('formio-submitted-data').textContent"
            ) { value ->
```

The response is

```
  value = ""{\"data\":{\"plantName\":\"Bhanu\",\"address\":\"Abcd\",\"totalCapacity\":25},\"isValid\":true}""
```

The response I have got is in a string. I have to convert it into JSON.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help https://www.bezkoder.com/kotlin-parse-json-gson/?

Comment: My JSON contain \ I have to convert value into a JSON object and forward it. I Don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Can you provide actual example that has `\\`?

Comment: It is like this .  ""{\"data\":{\"FIRSTFIELD\":\"1\",\"FIRSTFIELD2\":\"2}"" This is the JSON I AM GETTING

Comment: may be replace \" with just single quote and then try to use the same function

Comment: value.replace("\\","") is not working

Comment: webView.evaluateJavascript(
                    "document.getElementById('formio-submitted-data').textContent"
            ) { value ->  This is my code. and I am getting  value = "{\"data\":{\"plantName\":\"1\",\"address\":\"3\",\"totalCapacity\":2},\"isValid\":true}"   now I have to convert it to json object. but idk how to remove this \

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin escaping forward slashes usign Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258077/kotlin-escaping-forward-slashes-usign-gson)

Comment: no Altriwing it does not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.

The problem was in my script in webview.

What I did was

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener{
            var view=it
            webView.evaluateJavascript(
                    "JSON.parse(document.getElementById('formio-submitted-data').textContent)"
            ) { value ->
                if(value.length!=2){

                    val resp: JsonObject = JsonParser().parse(value).asJsonObject
                    val jsonObject = JsonObject()
                    jsonObject.add("data", resp)
```

I have changed the code inside evaluateJavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
val jsonParser = JsonParser()
val jsonObject = jsonParser.parse("your jsonString with backslash").asJsonObject
```

Comment: I was doing this before  val resp: JsonObject = JsonParser().parse(value).asJsonObject
                    val jsonObject = JsonObject()           . but my app crashes and it is giving me error                     
A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report         
                                                  A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 4443

Comment: Just to narrow down the problem, can you please try without \. I mean manually remove them and see if you still get this error. Just to find out this exception is because of \

Comment: I am trying to remove \ manually but   this         value.replace("//","") is not working. Or I should Iterate one by one. Kotlin does not have replaceAll function

Comment: Deprecated. Use static function instead - 
val jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString("your jsonString with backslash")